# Bokeh: update empty FactorRange in rect

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to show a correlation heatmap in bokeh. I'm inializing an empty Figure:

```
p2 = figure(x_range=[], y_range=[], plot_width=1200,plot_height=1200)
```

After the data source is selected and loaded (on button click), i do

```
p2.x_range.factors = corr["TABLE1"].unique().tolist()
p2.y_range.factors = corr["TABLE2"].unique().tolist()
source_heat_map.data = corr.to_dict('list')
p2.rect(
        x="TABLE1",
        y="TABLE2",
        width=1,
        height=1,
        source=source_heat_map,
        line_color=None,
        fill_color=bokeh_transform('value', mapper)
    )
```

and the heatmap appears, but the x_range.factors and y_range.factors stay blank.

If i initialize the Figure p2 with:

```
test = pd.read_csv("Heatmap.csv")
source_heat_map.data = test.to_dict('list')
name_a = test.columns[0]
name_b = test.columns[1]
p2 = figure(x_range=b, y_range=a, plot_width=1200,plot_height=1200)
p2.rect(
        x=name_b,
        y=name_a,
        width=1,
        height=1,
        source=source_heat_map,
        line_color=None,
        fill_color=bokeh_transform('value', mapper)
    )
```

and then choose another data source and click the button, it works and the  x_range.factors and y_range.factors get updated. What do i have to do to update the empty FactorRanges?

EDIT:

Here's a minimum working example. If you change `if True:` to `if False:` and initialize `p2 = figure(x_range=[], y_range=[], plot_width=1200,plot_height=1200)` the x_range.factors and y_range.factors as empty lists, it won't work anymore.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column,row, widgetbox, Spacer
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Paragraph, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, BasicTicker, TapTool, CustomJS,BoxSelectTool, Rect, FactorRange
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput, Div, Button, Dropdown, TableColumn, DataTable, CheckboxButtonGroup
from bokeh.models.annotations import Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show
from bokeh.client import push_session

from bokeh.transform import transform as bokeh_transform
from bokeh import events

from math import pi
import pandas as pd


def compute_corr():
    global matches
    corr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'TABLE1': {0: 'G', 1: 'L', 2: 'M', 3: 'N', 4: 'H', 5: 'T'}, 'value': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.5493847383480001, 2: 0.14649061756799993, 3: 0.39124820471999999, 4: 0.325265107675299999, 5: 0.668616128290099998}, 'TABLE2': {0: 'G', 1: 'G', 2: 'G', 3: 'G', 4: 'G', 5: 'G'}})

    p2.x_range.factors = corr["TABLE2"].unique().tolist()
    p2.y_range.factors = corr["TABLE1"].unique().tolist()
    source_heat_map.data = corr.to_dict('list')
    p2.rect(
            x="TABLE2",
            y="TABLE1",
            width=1,
            height=1,
            source=source_heat_map,
            line_color=None,
            fill_color=bokeh_transform('value', mapper)
        )

# You can use your own palette here
colors = ['#d7191c', '#fdae61', '#ffffbf', '#a6d96a', '#1a9641']


source_heat_map = ColumnDataSource(data = {})


b1 = Button(label="create", width=200, height=100)
b1.on_click(compute_corr)

mapper = LinearColorMapper(
        palette=colors, low=0, high=1)

if True:
    test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'TABLE1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F'}, 'value': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.8493847383480001, 2: 0.84649061756799993, 3: 0.89124820471999999, 4: 0.15265107675299999, 5: 0.068616128290099998}, 'TABLE2': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'}})
    source_heat_map.data = test.to_dict('list')
    name_a = 'TABLE1'
    name_b = 'TABLE2'
    a = list(set(test["TABLE1"].values))
    b = list(set(test["TABLE2"].values))
    print a,b
    p2 = figure(x_range=b, y_range=a, plot_width=1200,plot_height=1200)
    p2.rect(
            x=name_b,
            y=name_a,
            width=1,
            height=1,
            source=source_heat_map,
            line_color=None,
            fill_color=bokeh_transform('value', mapper)
        )
else:
    p2 = figure(x_range=[], y_range=[], plot_width=1200,plot_height=1200)

color_bar = ColorBar(
            color_mapper=mapper,
            location=(0, 0),
            ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)))

p2.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
p2.toolbar.logo = None
p2.toolbar_location = None
p2.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3

curdoc().add_root(row(b1,p2))
curdoc().title = "Correlations"
```

Comment: There is not enough information to go on. It could be be bug or usage error in your code Without a *complete minimal reproducer* to run and investigate, it is impossible to say.

Comment: The `if False` version works as expected for me with `0.13` and with `1.0dev`. What does "x_range.factors and y_range.factors stay blank" mean, exactly? The axis updates, and the new factors appear on the plot. I'm not sure what else you are expecting to happen. Maybe there is a bug in previous versions. If you are using an older version, that's important information you should always state when asking for assistance.

Comment: I was running version 0.12.10. Upgraded to version 0.13.0 and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An upgrade to Bokeh version 0.13.0 solved the issue.